# How to create linq to get all records group by columnname

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I have written below code but I am getting only one record of each `ExchangeDataId`.
Please help to get all the data which is `groupby` `ExchangeDataId`.

```
 var Report = ExchangeLeads.GroupBy(c => new
            {
                c.ExchangeDataId
            }).SelectMany(grouping=>grouping.Take(1)).ToList();
```

Comment: Do you want the records with a particular group id or a list of lists for each id?

Comment: I want the records with a particular groupid. But there may be more than 1 groupid.

Comment: This will give you a list of objects with an Id and items with that id `ExchangeLeads.GroupBy(c => c.ExchangeDataId).Select(group=> new { Id = group.Key, Items = group.ToList() }).ToList()` Do you want something like that?

Comment: Wait I will try this solution @IvanMladenov

Comment: Thank you @IvanMladenov. I got output as I expected.

Comment: Can you mark it as an accepted answer, I posted it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ExchangeLeads
  .GroupBy(c => c.ExchangeDataId)
  .Select(group=> new { Id = group.Key, Items = group.ToList() })
  .ToList()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following,

```
var result = ExchangeLeads.ToLookup(x => x.ExchangeDataId).Select(x => new { Id = x.Key, ExchangeLeads = x.ToList() }).ToList();
```

**Lookup is more efficient than GroupBy here.**